# react-native fetch api issue

Tags: android, ios, react-native

their is an issue with my react-native project . I am using `fetch api` to create a user profile. this is working fine on both **android and iOS devices**.

two days before m y domain was expired and then it I renew it. but the problem is that the API's are working fine on iOS device (I have test it on **iPhone 8 Plus**, **iPhone X max**, **iPhone 12 Pro Max**, **iPhone 15 Pro - Simulator**) . this is also working fine on some android devices (Like **xiaomi, inifix** -
both android 13) and not working on **Samsung galaxy A13** and **tecno pova 3** mobile both has android 12

Here is my code

```
const creataProfile = () => {
    let formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("xx", "Aftab");
    formdata.append("x1", "03408877654");
    formdata.append("x2", "PK");
    formdata.append("x3", "x1ddsf");
    formdata.append("user_profile_url", "");

    var requestOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        body: formdata,
    };

    fetch(`${Config.SERVER_URL}/register_user.php`, requestOptions)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(async (result) => {
            if (result.success) {
                alert("Login successfull!");
            } else {
                alert("Something went wrong. Please try again");
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            alert("Something went wrong. Please try again");
        });
};
```

**result :** Network request failed"

Comment: end point of api is just a string without any extension. 
try this /register_user
or ask you backend developer to about endpoint of user register api

Comment: this is a php api. its is working fine one iOS and some android devices. I have have added network security extensions but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the content-type in the header

```
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
```

I guess this issue about Flipper Network.

```
initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager())
```

in this file

```
/android/app/src/main/java/com/{your_project}/MainApplication.java
```

Comment: I have mentioned that this is working fine on iOS and some android devices. while not working on those device one which it was older version are. installed

Comment: Have you added a content-type to the header?

Comment: I guess this issue is about Flipper Network. check this also https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28551#issuecomment-610652110

Comment: yes. it is working fine. the problem was in the DNS.  on devices where I have already installed the application have this problem. after 48  hours the problem has been atomically solved.